# Detect bad JS that causes problems such as freezes

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JS script, which seems to work fine. However, at random points it makes the browser freeze. The latter especially happens soon/often on mobile devices. Is there any tool to check what part messes it up i.e. perhaps needs too much RAM/CPU?

I know there are things such as 'Profiles' in the Chrome DevTools, however I don't have enough experience to see where the problems lie. If this is the right one to do so, are there any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to bear in mind is that JavaScript is single threaded. If one function takes a long time then it will block the event loop so other functions can't run. For example, animations such as you find in jQuery work by calling a function repeatedly on a timer. If a function blocks the event loop then, depending on your page and what's in it, lots of functionality can be degraded and the browser can appear to freeze.

So most problems are caused by a function that takes too long to execute.

'Profiles' is a good thing to use for this. Start a profile, run your page until something 'bad' happens, and then look at the result. Chrome will list the functions in order of how much time they spend executing. If you find one function takes more time than you think it should, there's your culprit. The more times a function is called the more time it will take executing, but if you wrote your code then you should know how often various functions are called.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I got a setTimeouts, clearTimeouts couple, which might screw things up...